# How to make C# Azure Function work with Static Web App?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I created a Static Web App per the instructions on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/getting-started?tabs=angular). The Javsscript Azure Function worked.

Then I replaced the API with a C# version. Now when I publish the Function to Azure, I get the following error.

`The function language 'dotnet' is unsupported or invalid. The following languages are valid: node.`

Is this due to **Azure Static WebApp** wont support **dotnet/C#**? How can I use C# inside a **Static Web App** if it can support?

Comment: Hi, any update on this question?

Comment: C# is now supported: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/azure-static-web-apps-with-blazor/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

c# functions are supported for azure static-web-apps.
The Visual-Studio-Code [Azure Static Web Apps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-azuretools.vscode-azurestaticwebapps) extension can create all the necessary files for you automatically, according to the build-workflow file.

On this website you can find a detailed description about how to do it:
https://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/free-developer-tools/blog/azure-functions-static-web-apps/

Answer (score 0):

The API Functions app in C# does not be supported.

Azure Static Web Apps provides an API through Azure Functions. The capabilities of Azure Functions are focused to a specific set of features that enable you to create an API for a web app and allow the web app to connect to API securely. And the API Functions app must be in JavaScript.

Have a look of this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis#constraints

Comment: At time of writing, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis#constraints states "The API must either be a JavaScript, C#, or Python Azure Functions app." I can't get it to work tho.

Comment: I have a static web app with c# Azure function as api. I might be able to help you if you can share your code on GitHub.

Comment: I don't know what [the link in the answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/apis#constraints) said when the answer was posted (always be sure to quote relevant material!!), but it now says *"The Azure Functions app must either be in Node.js 12, Node.js 14, Node.js 16, Node.js 18 (public preview), **.NET Core 3.1, .NET 6.0,** Python 3.8, Python 3.9 or Python 3.10 (public preview)."* *(my emphasis)*, so the answer is (now) incorrect.